# How to invoke an interactive elisp interpreter in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, interpreter

Right now I write expressions in the `*scratch*` buffer and test them by evaluating with <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-e</kbd>. I would really appreciate having an interactive interpreter like SLIME or irb, in which I could test Emacs Lisp expressions.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It's easy to evaluate Lisp expressions in Inferior Emacs-Lisp Mode:

```
M-x ielm
```

You can read more about this feature in the [Emacs manual section on "Lisp Interaction"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#Lisp-Interaction)

Answer (score 21):

[Eshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html#Top) is another option for an interactive Elisp interpreter.

```
M-x eshell
```

Not only is it a command shell like bash (or cmd.exe if on Windows) but you can also interactively write and execute Elisp code.

```
~ $ ls
foo.txt
bar.txt
~ $ (+ 1 1)
2
```

Comment: ok, that's just... fascinating... the mixing ability... I'll definitely have to play more with this.  Even though it's an indirect answer to the question, I'm glad this answer is here!

`$ echo (buffer-name) | sed -e 's/\*/X/g'` gives `XeshellX`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Your best bet is the `*scratch*` buffer.  You can make it more like a REPL by first turning on the debugger:

```
M-x set-variable debug-on-error t
```

Then use `C-j` instead of `C-x C-e`, which will insert the result of evaluating the expression into the buffer on the line after the expression.  Instead of things like command history, `* * *` and so forth, you just move around the `*scratch*` buffer and edit.

If you want things like `* * *` to work, more like a usual REPL, try `ielm`.

```
M-x ielm
```

Answer (score 2):

To run just one elisp expression you can use M-: shortcut and enter expression in mini-buffer.  For other cases you can use *scratch* buffer

Comment: M-: runs the command eval-expression (that's shift-alt-<colon key>)

Answer (score 1):

In the `*scratch*` buffer, just type C-j to evaluate the expression before point.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're really interested in a literal REPL for emacs it is possible to write one using the -batch mode of emacs:

```
(require 'cl)

(defun read-expression ()
  (condition-case
      err
      (read-string "> ")
    (error
     (message "Error reading '%s'" form)
     (message (format "%s" err)))))

(defun read-expression-from-string (str)
  (condition-case
      err
      (read-from-string str)
    (error
     (message "Error parsing '%s'" str)
     (message (format "%s" err))
     nil)))

(defun repl ()
  (loop for expr = (read-string "> ") then (read-expression)
        do
        (let ((form (car (read-expression-from-string expr))))
          (condition-case
              err
              (message " => %s" (eval form))
            (error
             (message "Error evaluating '%s'" form)
             (message (format "%s" err)))))))

(repl)
```

You can call this from the command line, or, as you seem to want, from within an emacs buffer running a shell:

```
kburton@hypothesis:~/projects/elisp$ emacs -batch -l test.el
Loading 00debian-vars...
> (defvar x '(lambda (y) (* y 100)))
 => x
> (funcall x 0.25)
 => 25.0
> 
kburton@hypothesis:~/projects/elisp$
```

Comment: This looks more complicated than it should be - running a shell, which runs another emacs in batch mode, which runs the REPL, all inside the main emacs runtime. Anyway, it solves my problem, so thank you for help!

Comment: This REPL implementation doesn't handle multi-line inputs. If you don't end an expression in a single line it gives:

    Error parsing '(whatever'
    (end-of-file repl.el)

Is there an easy way to fix that?